# Using regex to remove text between delimiter in java

Tags: java, regex

Hi I'm trying to remove all code between `/*` and `*/` in a string of multiple lines. I have this so far:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile).useDelimiter("\\Z");
String file = scan.next();
String next = file.replaceAll("((/\\*)(\\s|\\S)*(\\*/))", "");
```

However when I try to run this with an input file that has multiple cases of `/*` and `*/` it removes everything between them.  For example, in this input

```
/* first comment */
a = b;
//test
if a = c;
// whatever
if a = d;
/* this
is a

test
*/

/* another */
```

It will remove everything between the first `/*` and the last `*/` at the end of the file. Essentially replacing the entire text with a blank space. How do I limit it to the first case of `/**` and `**/`?

Comment: Make your quantifier lazy - `(\\s|\\S)*?`. But in fact, that's only the beginning of the problem. What would you do with `/*` inside string literals, for example?

Comment: By the way, the same idea is much better expressed either with character class (`[\\s\\S]`) or enabling `/s` modifier on regex.

Comment: Please post the file content to get clear idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `greedy` quantifier. Your `(\\s|\\S)*` will match everything till it finds the last `*/`, till where results in the complete pattern can be successfully matched.

You can make the quantifier reluctant by adding a `?` after `*`.

```
"((/\\*)(\\s|\\S)*?(\\*/))"
```

Also, you can simplify your regex like this: -

```
String next = file.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/", "");
```

`(?s)` -> Is used for `SingleLine` matching. It is an alternative for `Pattern.DOTALL` to be used in `String.replaceAll()`. So, your `dot(.)` would include everything including newline. And you don't need `(\\s|\\S)` for that.

Comment: Perfect answer, I was trying to make it reluctant but on the /* and */ parts so it looks like I need to read a little more on greedy, reluctant, and possessive and get a solid grip on what they do. Works perfect now, thank you!

Comment: Actually, `(?s)` is used for DOTALL aka Singleline mode.  `(?m)` is the one for Multiline mode.